# Submodule file links in SSDT predeploy or postdeploy script producing a 72001 error

Tags: sql-server, git, deployment, git-submodules, sql-server-data-tools

In a SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) project in Visual Studio, we have a "core" set of SQL objects that are included in each SQL project we do - kind of like a class library. We keep these "core" SQL objects in a separate Git repo, and then include them in other projects as a Git submodule.

Once the "core" submodule is linked to the main project, we include the submodule files in our .SQLPROJ file like so:

`<Content Include="..\CoreSubmodule\ProjectFolder\Scripts\**\*.*">
      <Link>Scripts\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>`

This works great for regular .sql files in project - they show up with a special icon in Visual Studio indicating that it's a referenced file, and the build engine is able to resolve references/dependencies just fine. Where we're running into a snag, though, is with our Pre- and Post-Deployment scripts.

We have a series of "core" Pre- and Post-Deployment master scripts that are common among projects, which we've just introduced into our "core" submodule. Here's how the directory structure looks at a high-level:

`/Scripts/
    /PostDeploy/
        _PostDeployMaster.sql
        /ReferenceData/
            ReferenceDataScript1.sql`

In the above structure:

- _PostDeploymentMaster.sql is a *local* file in the project, and is set to Build Action = "PostDeploy". It has a reference to the *ReferenceDataScript1.sql file
- ReferenceDataScript1.sql is a *reference* to a file that physically
  exists in the submodule directory (one level up from our project),
  and is set to Build Action = "None"

  - Note that Visual Studio displays it in the /ReferenceData/ folder as a linked file

The _PostDeploymentMaster script references other sub-scripts via a SQLCMD reference:

`:r .\ReferenceData\ReferenceDataScript1.sql
go`

Trying to build the project in this manner produces a SQL72001 error in Visual Studio ("The included file  does not exist"). Obviously if we physically place the ReferenceDataScript1.sql file in the directory (without having a reference), it builds just fine.

Options we've explored include having a non-Build "buffer" script between the PostDeploy master and the core subscripts (same error), and having pre and post build actions set to physically copy files back and forth from the submodule to the project to satisfy the build engine (a little too hacky for our taste).

Has anyone run into this issue, or have a serviceable workaround?

Comment: Does using ..\..\ etc \ReferenceData work?  Assuming that you have it in some higher level folder, hopefully consistent with all of your repos.

Comment: Can you set the build action to "copy"?

Comment: @PeterSchott - that method will allow us to build, but it won't copy the scripts into the right location for our DACPAC deployment, unfortunately.

Comment: @user1443098 - these are the options we get for Build Action: Build, Build Extension Configuration, Compile, Deployment Extension Configuration, None, PostDeploy, PreDeploy, RefactorLog. The "CopyToOutputDirectory" option is set to "Copy Always"

Comment: I thought pre/post-deploy scripts were built into the dacpac itself. Admittedly, haven't looked in a while.  The only thing I can think of outside of that is some sort of "pre-build" type process that does that copying for you.  Either that or you use composite projects so you include that project/dacpac in each project you deploy and push them all together or push the "common" one first, then the main one.

Comment: @PeterSchott - You're correct - Pre/Post scripts will render all referenced scripts into a single set of Pre/Post files inside of a DACPAC. The submodule references in the Post-script though are preventing the build from succeeding and producing our DACPAC at all. We've posted the problem out on the MS developer community page to see if we can get an official response; I'll update this Stack post if anything happens there: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311982/ssdt-build-error-72001-the-included-file-does-not.html

Comment: How many boxes does this need to work on? Any chance a symlink could do this for you?  (horrible idea, but if it's that or copying the files to each folder)  I still think for what you're describing, composite projects might be the better solution. Common stuff in one project and the DB-specific stuff in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wound up working around this issue by using **Peter Schott**'s suggested fix in the original question's comments - using relative paths back to the submodule on disk instead of the "virtual" link inside of the actual Visual Studio SQL project.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching how can I organize SSDT project with Submodules and found your question.
I did some realizations, but I used "virtual" link inside of the actual Visual Studio SQL project. Here is my test projects.

- https://github.com/gnevashev/Core
- https://github.com/gnevashev/Installation01

In .sqlproj, I added:

```
<Build Include="Core\**\*.sql" Exclude="Core\**\*PostDepl*.sql" />
```

And in project PostDeploy Script, I added link on Core PostDeploy Script:

```
:r .\Core\Script.PostDeploymentPopulateData.sql
```